# Creating folders from a single column in a csv and using other column to rename files into folders

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
dc_identifier,aubrey_identifier
AR0776-280206-LT513-01,metadc1084267
AR0776-280206-LT513-02,metadc1083385
AR0776-280206-LT513-03,metadc1084185
AR0776-280206-LT513-04,metadc1083449
AR0776-280206-LT513-05,metadc1084294
AR0776-280206-LT513-06,metadc1083393
AR0776-280206-LT513-07,metadc1083604
AR0776-280206-LT513-08,metadc1083956
AR0776-280206-LT513-09,metadc1083223
AR0776-280206-LT513-10,metadc1084224
```

I need to create folders with the "metadc#######" names within the directory that the script will live in.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import os
import fileinput
path = 'C:\Users\gpp0020\Desktop\TestDir'

textFile = 'C:\Users\gpp0020\Desktop\TestDir\kxas_ids.csv'

myList = open(textFile, 'rb+')
for line in myList:
    for item in line.strip().split(','):
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, item))
        print 'created', item
```

However!  I also need the program to grab files that are named with the identifiers (`AR0776-280206-LT513-01`, etc) and put them in the corresponding metadc number, according to the csv.  Each file is doubled (one .mkv file, and one .mkv.md5 checksum file) and both need to go into the folder.

What's the best way to go about this?

Comment: You should use the `csv` module instead of parsing CSV file with `line.strip().split()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `csv` library to help with reading the file in:

```
import csv
import os
import shutil

path = r'C:\Users\gpp0020\Desktop\TestDir'

with open('kxas_ids.csv', 'r', newline='') as f_input:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    header = next(csv_input)

    for dv, aubrey in csv_input:
        os.makedirs(os.path.join(path, aubrey), exist_ok=True)
        mkv = '{}.mkv'.format(dv)
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, mkv), os.path.join(path, aubrey, mkv))
        mkv_md5 = '{}.mkv.md5'.format(dv)
        shutil.copy2(os.path.join(path, mkv_md5), os.path.join(path, aubrey, mkv_md5))
```

This would for example:

1. Create a folder called `C:\Users\gpp0020\Desktop\TestDir\metadc108426`
2. Copy a file called `AR0776-280206-LT513-01.mkv` into it.
3. Copy a file called `AR0776-280206-LT513-01.mkv.md5` into it.
4. It assumes that all files are found in `path`

Comment: This created the folders, but didn't put the files in.  It said  `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:/Users/gpp0020/Desktop/TestDir\\metadc1084267'`

Comment: That would happen if you ran it a second time without first deleting all the sub folders first.

Comment: You can add `exist_ok=True` to make it ignore the error.